# Ramification index in a number field extension

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I've a basic question:

Let $L/K$ be an extension of number fields, $\mathfrak p$ a prime ideal of $\mathcal O_K$ and let $\mathfrak p \mathcal O_L=\prod_i P_i^{e_i}$ where $P_i$ are primes in $L$ and let $w_i$, $v$ be the valuations corresponding to $P_i$ and $\mathfrak p$ respectively.

Is it true that the ramification index $e_i$ is equal to the group index $(w_i(L^\times):v(K^\times))$ for each $i$?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, kit seems to be the definition, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=Bb30CjGW7EAC&pg=PA416&lpg=PA416&dq=ramification+index+e_i+is+equal+to+valuation+group+index&source=bl&ots=BtP0l4G7bQ&sig=s9OTLzeg59DGAwnKXauJ8XVV9BU&hl=de&sa=X&ei=X-CGVfy4IMiqUavSgrAC&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=ramification%20index%20e_i%20is%20equal%20to%20valuation%20group%20index&f=false).